# Are there any APIs available for a firefox WebExtension to create and write to a file in local file system

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm looking to create and write to a file in local file system from my firefox WebExtension. Are there any APIs available to achieve this?

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1246236

Comment: You can use the downloads API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads) with a blob or data uri but that requires that you either write to the downloads directory or open a "save file" dialog to let the user choose where to save the file.  The ability to silently write to an arbitrary location on the filesystem would break the webextensions goal of a safe-by-default sandbox.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I was able to accomplish the task with blob and downloads API. :)

Comment: While the blob and downloads API work well for some use cases, for other ones they are an extremely poor fit. I'm trying to get spun up on Firefox extension development now and was appalled to see that they seem to have deprecated the old SDK without a clear path for what seems like such a critical feature. @AndrewSwan - are there any other options? I've got a neat idea but this seems like it's going to make it hard to implement well.

Comment: You didn't ask a specific question so its hard to say what your options are.  You might find a mozilla mailing list (eg dev-addons) a more productive venue for asking this question.